# Need flatpak 1.14.4 on Ubuntu 22.04, but apt installs flatpak 1.12.7 as latest

Tags: apt, upgrade, windows-subsystem-for-linux, flatpak

I want flatpak 1.14.4 for the resolution of [this issue](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/3397) when attempting to run kmail on WSL Ubuntu. When I run `sudo apt upgrade flatpak`, it says that the latest version of flatpak is 1.12.7-1. [flatpak 1.14.4](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/releases/tag/1.14.4) was released in March, so the apt database has surely updated by now. How can I get flatpak 1.14.4?

##### Update 11-27-2023 2:19 PM

```
$ sudo apt install flatpak=1.14.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package flatpak is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  xdg-desktop-portal flatpak-builder

E: Version '1.14.4' for 'flatpak' was not found
```

But:

```
$ apt list flatpak
Listing... Done
flatpak/jammy,now 1.12.7-1 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: Did you update the apt database first with `sudo apt update` ?

Comment: @SorenA Yes, I did.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: flatpak `1.14.4-2` is available for my release, but you didn't provide you release details. Packages (esp. *deb*) are built for specific releases, and Ubuntu being a *stable* release system keeps the same packages for the life of the product, with only security fixes backported (*to version you originally had*); ie. if using a 2022-April release - you'll remain on software that was *stable* at that time with security fixes backported only (*unless you move to alternate package sources intentionally*).

Comment: @guiverc Thank you for the information; it is truly helpful. But I still need flatpak 1.14.4 on Ubuntu 22.04, so the linked question does not solve my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use 22.04 (Jammy), then `1.12.7-1` is the recent version of the  `flatpak`-package. This package comes from the universe repository, Canonical does not provide updates for the package, some updates may (or may not) be provided by the community, obviously this was not the case.

However, you can get version `1.14.4-1` from the [Flatpak team on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Eflatpak/+archive/ubuntu/stable?field.series_filter=jammy):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flatpak/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade (if flatpak is installed already, otherwise use sudo apt install flatpak)
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Then this answer will work for you.